Actualice Moodle pero no reconoce la version actual de PHP
Actualicé Moodle a la versión 4.4.2, seguí todos los pasos como indica la guía.
pero  me sale el siguiente error:
Moodle 4.4 or later requires at least PHP 8.1 (currently using version 8.0.30). Some servers may have multiple PHP versions installed, are you using the correct executable?
aunque cuando reviso la version instalada de PHP es 8.1.29
supongo que es algo del archivo config.php
pero no se como arreglarlo
le paso a alguien? o saben como puedo arreglarlo?
Gracias!

Qué servidor de php es? Estás en linux? Windows? Dá mas info del servidor como tal

esta en un servidor con Ubuntu 22.4, con nginx, y tiene instalado el PHP 8.1.29
esta alojando en un hosting  tipo KVM

Si te dice que tienes usando esa versión, prueba con:
sudo a2dismod php8.0.30
sudo a2enmod php8.1.29
sudo service apache2 restart

Alí estarías usando la última version de php que indicas que ya instalaste.
